# HTML, CSS Chatbox Aligning all the element respectively using percentages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create the User Interface of a side chat with a fixed position. My issue is that the height of each section (the header of the chat, the main body, and the input field) are not in perspective and proportion. How do I use percentages to make them align in a way that when the page is resized, it will adjust to it?

My HTML Code:

```
<div id="chatContainer" class="chatContainer">
    <div class="chatWrapper">
        <div class="chatHeader">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chatCloseBtn" onclick="closeChat()">&#10006;</a>
            <div class="chatTitle">FortniteProSnipes Public Chat</div>
            <div class="chatSubText">This is a general chat for all members of FortniteProSnipes</div>
        </div>
        <div class="chatBox">
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
            trgr: grtgrt<br>        
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
        </div></div>
        <input type="text" class="chatInputBox" name="chat-message" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript with the Chat Box:

```
<script>
function openNav() {
    if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
        // Mobile friendly section
        document.getElementById("chatContainer").style.width = "100%";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("chatContainer").style.width = "450px";
    }
}

function closeChat() {
    document.getElementById("chatContainer").style.width = "0";
}
</script>
```

Styling of Chat Box:

```
.chatHeader {
    height: 20%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid DarkOrange;
}
.chatContainer {
    height: calc(100vh - 92px);
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 92px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.chatWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.chatBreak {
    color: DarkOrange;
    background-color: #ee7600;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    height: 2px;
}
.chatTitle {
    color: white;
    font-family: BurbankBigCondensed-Black;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.chatCloseBtn {
    font-family: BurbankBigCondensed-Black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    transition: all 0.20s linear;
}
.chatCloseBtn:hover {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
}
.chatBox {
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border-top: 2px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
    min-height: calc(75% - 42px);
}
.chatSubText {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #BEBEBE;
    font-family: BurbankBigCondensed-Black;
}
.chatInputBox {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border: none;
    border-top: 2px solid DarkOrange;
    border-bottom: 2px solid DarkOrange;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    min-height: calc(5% - 4px);
}
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z5t9pj8r/

I need the chat look in proportion with no overlapping of elements if I was to change the height of the actual page. I think the text may need to change from px to vh or % or something to be in proportion too. Im not too sure when making everything in proportion to each other. Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Look into view port units

Answer (score -1):

[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/rogatnev-nikita/pen/GwNYXV)

```js
function openChat() {
   document.getElementById("chatContainer").style.display = "block";
}

function closeChat() {
    document.getElementById("chatContainer").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.chatContainer {
    display: none;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    transition: 0.5s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    .chatContainer {
        max-width: calc(100vw / 3);
        height: 100%;
    }
}

.chatWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.chatHeader {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-bottom: 2px solid DarkOrange;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 115px;
}

.chatCloseBtn {
    order: 2;
    font-family: BurbankBigCondensed-Black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.20s linear;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.chatCloseBtn:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.chatTitle {
    order: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    font-family: BurbankBigCondensed-Black;
    font-size: 24px;
    max-width: 90%;
}

.chatSubText {
    order: 3;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #BEBEBE;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.chatBreak {
    color: DarkOrange;
    background-color: #ee7600;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    height: 2px;
}

.chatBox {
    padding: 20px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border-top: 2px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
    flex-grow: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.chatInputBox {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border: none;
    border-top: 2px solid DarkOrange;
    border-bottom: 2px solid DarkOrange;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    resize: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openChat()">Open Chat</button>

<section id="chatContainer" class="chatContainer">
    <div class="chatWrapper">
        
        <header class="chatHeader">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chatCloseBtn" onclick="closeChat()">&#10006;</a>
            <h1 class="chatTitle">
                FortniteProSnipes Public Chat
            </h1>
            <p class="chatSubText">
                This is a general chat for all members of FortniteProSnipes
            </p>
        </header>
        
        <div class="chatBox">
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
            trgr: grtgrt<br>        
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
            trgr: grtgrt<br>
        </div>
        
        <textarea class="chatInputBox" name="chat-message"></textarea>
    </div>
</section>
```